# PHP recursive loop a "file tree" array cant get all keys

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I have an array like this:

[image]

In this array I have folders (dir1, dir2, dir3, etc...) and files. I need to list all the directories and files but printing which is the parent of each element, example: dir2 is child of dir1, dir4 is child of dir2, etc...

The problem is that my recursive function can't iterate over "dir2" because it only obtains "dir3" as directory, directories "dir4", "dir5", "dir7" are missing.

[image]

Im breaking my head but I don't get it to work...

This is my code:

```
    <?php
$files = array();
array_push($files, array('root/dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.mkv', "Archivo de vídeo"));
array_push($files, array('root/test.png', "Archivo de imagen"));
array_push($files, array('root/dir1/dir2/dir4/file2.mkv', "Archivo de vídeo2"));
array_push($files, array('root/dir1/dir2/dir4/dir5/file3.mkv', "Archivo de vídeo3"));
array_push($files, array('root/dir1/dir2/dir4/dir5/dir7/file4.mkv', "Archivo de vídeo4"));

$filearray=[];

function scanpath($patharray, $filesize) {
    $tree=[];
    if(count($patharray)===1) {
        $filename=array_pop($patharray);
        $tree[] = ['nombre'=>$filename, 'descripcion'=>$filesize];
    } else {
        $pathpart = array_pop($patharray);
        $tree[$pathpart] = scanpath($patharray,$filesize);
    }
    return $tree;
}

foreach($files as $fileentry) {
    $patharray = array_reverse(explode('/',$fileentry[0]));
    $thisarray = scanpath($patharray,$fileentry[1]);
    $filearray = array_merge_recursive($filearray,$thisarray);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($filearray);
echo '</pre>';


function test($arr, $ultimoDirectorio = "") {

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {
            // Directory

            if ($key != "" && !is_numeric($key)) {
                $ultimoDirectorio = $key;
            }

            if (!is_numeric(key($value)) && !is_numeric($key)) {
                echo("Directory ".key($value)." inside ".$key."<br>");
            }

            test($value, $ultimoDirectorio);

        } else {
            // File
            $nombreFichero = $arr['nombre'];
            $descripcionFichero = $arr['descripcion'];
            echo("Inside: ".$ultimoDirectorio." => File: ".$nombreFichero." - Description: ".$descripcionFichero."<br>");
            break;
        }

    }
}

echo(test($filearray, ""));
```

The function that iterates is called "test".

Thank's you... this is giving me a serious headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the condition for checking parant child dir is no valid.

`if (!is_numeric(key($value)) && !is_numeric($key)) {` this line is not required. you need to be using `$key` and `$ultimoDirectorio` to check paranet child dirs.

Also, `$ultimoDirectorio = $key` loses state for file parent. So we will need 2 variables for parent pointing.

Example below

```php
    <?php
$files = array();
array_push($files, array('root/dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.mkv', "Archivo de vídeo"));
array_push($files, array('root/test.png', "Archivo de imagen"));
array_push($files, array('root/dir1/dir2/dir4/file2.mkv', "Archivo de vídeo2"));
array_push($files, array('root/dir1/dir2/dir4/dir5/file3.mkv', "Archivo de vídeo3"));
array_push($files, array('root/dir1/dir2/dir4/dir5/dir7/file4.mkv', "Archivo de vídeo4"));

$filearray=[];

function scanpath($patharray, $filesize) {
    $tree=[];
    if(count($patharray)===1) {
        $filename=array_pop($patharray);
        $tree[] = ['nombre'=>$filename, 'descripcion'=>$filesize];
    } else {
        $pathpart = array_pop($patharray);
        $tree[$pathpart] = scanpath($patharray,$filesize);
    }
    return $tree;
}

foreach($files as $fileentry) {
    $patharray = array_reverse(explode('/',$fileentry[0]));
    $thisarray = scanpath($patharray,$fileentry[1]);
    $filearray = array_merge_recursive($filearray,$thisarray);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($filearray);
echo "</pre>\n";


function test($arr, $ultimoDirectorio = "",$filedir="") {

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {
            // Directory

            if ($key != "" && !is_numeric($key)) {
                if ($ultimoDirectorio == ""){
                    echo "Directory $key is top level dir \n";
                } else {
                    echo "Directory $key inside $ultimoDirectorio \n";
                }
            }

            test($value, $key,$ultimoDirectorio);

        } else {
            // File
            $nombreFichero = $arr['nombre'];
            $descripcionFichero = $arr['descripcion'];
            echo("Inside: ".$filedir." => File: ".$nombreFichero." - Description: ".$descripcionFichero."\n");
            break;
        }

    }
}

echo(test($filearray, ""));
```

Comment: THANK'S YOU. It works perfect.I did not imagine that I need a second variable for parent pointing.